# How would i go about creating a external url monitor?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox

How would I go about creating an application that can somehow see URLs I am viewing in most popular browsers?

Can it be done out of process?
In what ways can this be done?
Can it be done without browser plugins?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is use a proxy server.. prevent html access out except from the proxy server so they have to use it, then all url requests go to the proxy server, even if you choose to make it yourself, then you can collect the URLS either from logs or something and off you go.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Do you mean a proxy socket that listens on port 80 and redirects the connection to the localhost, handles the packets, then spits them back to the original socket? or do you mean something else? cheers

Comment: Sort of - a proxy server is just that, it handles all web requests, so it can run on any port, and the client connects to it, makes the connection on the clients behalf and hands it back - it can be on a different machine - a lot of companies do it etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install something in your network infrastructure and then collect data from it.

That could be a proxy server (eg [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp)) or you can look at tools like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (pcap).